# Solving Polynomial Equations and Inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> The distance, in km, of a ship from its harbour is modeled by the function 
>   $d(t)= -3t^3 + 3t^2 + 18t$
>   where $t$ is the time elapsed in hours since departure from the harbour.

a) When does the ship return to harbour?

b) Estimate the time that the ship begins its return trip back to the harbour.

c) When is the ship $24$ km from the harbour?

I believe I have figured the first part of this question out.  I substituted values for "$t$" until the equation ended with a value of zero.  This value was $d(3)$.  Meaning that it takes the ship 3 hours to reach the harbour.  The other questions I am just not sure how to approach.  c) I began by substituting $24$ as my distance, but I am not sure what to do after that.

Comment: Don't you have to solve $-3t^3+3t^2+18t=24$ ?

Answer (score -1):

As of your answer to a), I wouldn't recommend that, instead do:
$$d(t)=0\implies -3t^3+3t^2+18t=0\implies 3t(-t^2+t+6)=0\implies t=0\text{ or }-t^2+t+6=0\implies t=0\text{ or }t=3\text{ or }t=-2$$
Do you understand how we found these solutions? It should be clear that from the above we can conclude that the ship returns at $t=3$

As of b), when would you expect this?

As of c), we have to solve $d(t)=24$. Now, our method of a) doesn't work anymore, since we have to solve $$-3t^3+3t^2+18t-24=0$$
we can't factor out a term $t$. Substituting some standard values is the only solution (actually there are ways to solve this, but I don't wan't to bother you with that!). And then we find $t=1$ is a solution.

Comment: Why would t=0? I don't see how that makes sense

Comment: Are you familiar with the statement $A\cdot B=0\iff A=0\text{ or } B=0$?

Comment: No, I don't think I have been familiarized with that

Comment: Alright, then I think I can assume you don't understand the rest of my answer either? If that is the case (at least if you can't follow my answer for a), I suggest you ask your teacher about how to solve this, working all of the theory out in this post would be way too elaborate

Comment: Well from the answers I understand that d(t) should equal zero, but it's the t=0 that throws me off and makes me off track of the rest of the question.

Comment: Yeah, than I'm afraid your question is a little too elementary for this website, sorry!

Comment: What grade are you in? What are you familiar with concering this topic?

Comment: I am actually graduated, it's just been a few years since I have done this so I have been trying to refresh myself on it all again.

Comment: Alright, what book are you using? Is there any explanation in it?

Comment: Not a book.  It's an online course.

Comment: What does your course say about solving general equations? Maybe you should reread that part and see which methods can be applied here! Those methods include *factoring out variables*, *solving polynomials of second degree* etc.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been doing.  I will have to come back to this .

Comment: I can get the t= -2 or t=3 on my own since as you factor it through the quadratic formula was needed which ended up with these two answers.  However I still am not following where the t=0 comes from because time cannot equal zero for the ship the reach the harbour.  That is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: Time also can't equal -2, but note that we're talking about two different things. The ship reaching the harbor is a real event, and the equation we're solving is a **model** of the reality. Interpretation of the model will result in the conclusion that $t=3$, since $t=-2$ and $t=0$ are no possibilities!

Comment: Yes I understand that, but where does the t=0 come from?  The only time zero came up was when the distance was set to zero.

Comment: Yes, we set the distance to zero, then we work out the equation. We factored out $3t$ to remain with a second-order equation. But when factoring out $3t$, the solution to the equation is $3t=0$ or *second-order formula* $=0$

Comment: Oh okay, now I see that.  I had forgotten about the 3t there when it was factored out.

Comment: So for part b), it's asking an estimation of when it first begins to return back to the harbour.  Is there a calculation that can be done here to get a more accurate result, or is it simply asking for a personal guess?  Since I do not know the entire distance it has travelled away from the harbour.

Comment: You could answer this question by differentiation, but I strongly doubt if that is part of this part of your course, so I would stick to the personal guess ;)

Comment: Okay.  SO on to c), I would presume that I would begin this by substituting 24 as my distance.  So, 24= -3t^3 + 3t^2 + 18t and I am going to need to isolate for "t".  So should I subtract 24 from both sides to make the left side =0?

Comment: Exactly, but unfortunately there is no algebraic way to deduce a solution, so trying out suffices

Comment: Are you so sure that $-3\cdot 1^3+3\cdot 1^2+18\cdot1=24$ ???